# A more mathematical way to solve the first problem in the project Euler archives.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, gcd-and-lcm

Okay so the problem itself is really simple,

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Many people will just solve this using a for loop and and the modulo operator like this,

```
s = 0
for x in range(1000):
  if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
    s += x
print(s)
```

But I felt the need to solve it using just mathemathics and came up with this: Let $s$ be the sum, $n=10$ and $x_1 = 3, x_2=5$. We have,

$$
\newcommand\c[1]{\left\lceil#1\right\rceil}
\newcommand\p[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand\ep{\varepsilon}
$$

\begin{align*}
s &= (3 + 6 + 9) + (5) \\ &= x_1(1 + 2 + 3) + x_2(1) \\ &= x_1\sum_{i=1}^{m_1}i + x_2\sum_{i=1}^{m_2}i && m_i = \c{\frac{n}{x_i}}-1 \\ &= x_1\frac{m_1(m_1+1)}{2} + x_2\frac{m_2(m_2+1)}{2} \\ &= x_1\frac{\p{\c{\frac{n}{x_1}}-1}\c{\frac{n}{x_1}}}{2} + x_2\frac{\p{\c{\frac{n}{x_2}}-1}\c{\frac{n}{x_2}}}{2} \\
&= \sum_{i}\p{x_i\frac{\p{\c{\frac{n}{x_i}}-1}\c{\frac{n}{x_i}}}{2}}
\end{align*}

At this point, we have over summed since $x_1, x_2$ may share multiples. So if they are relatively prime, we can write:

$$
s = \sum_{i}\p{x_i\frac{\p{\c{\frac{n}{x_i}}-1}\c{\frac{n}{x_i}}}{2}} - \ep
$$

where $\ep = x_3\frac{\p{\c{\frac{n}{x_3}}-1}\c{\frac{n}{x_3}}}{2}$ for $x_3 = x_1x_2$. But now the issue is the assumption that $x_i$'s are relatively prime or there is only two of them. Consider a more general case where $x_i \in X \supset \mathbb{N}$ and $x_i < n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is there an elegant way to state $\ep$ in this case? I feel like I need to use LCM somehow but can't quite think how.

---

**Example**. Let $X = \{2,3,9\}$ and $n = 10$. We have:

\begin{align*}
2&:\{2,4,6,8\} \\
3&:\{3,6,9\} \\
9&:\{9\}
\end{align*}

Now, we need a way to count (or have the same effect thereof) the 6 and 9 only once.

Comment: The ones that have been double-counted are precisely the multiples of lcm$(x_1,x_2)$. (It's a theorem that $x_1$ divides $a$ and $x_2$ divides $a$ if and only if lcm$(x_1,x_2)$ divides $a$.)

Comment: Extending the comment of @GregMartin, when dealing with more than two variables (e.g. $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$) then you need the [Inclusion-Exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  In fact, you actually manually derived this principle for the special case where the number of variables equals 2.

Comment: Okay so the correct answer in case of the example is 32. and $LCM(2,3,9) = 18$, though I am having trouble seeing how I can apply this to 47 (the oversum) to get the right 32?

Comment: @scribe You should consider LCM of each non-empty subset of $\{2, 3, 9\}$: $LCM(2,3)$, $LCM(3,9)$, $LCM(2,9)$, $LCM(2,3,9)$, $LCM(2)$, $LCM(3)$, $LCM(9)$.

Comment: I suppose it is not clear to me how should I use the LCM's of each of the elements of the power set here?

Comment: @scribe The following is for your $X$ but with $n=19$, to demonstrate the effect of $LCM(2,3,9)$:

$$\begin{align*}s &= LCM(2)(1+2+\cdots+9) + LCM(3)(1+2+\cdots+6) + LCM(9)(1+2)\\
&- LCM(2,3)(1+2+3) - LCM(3,9)(1+2)-LCM(2,9)(1)\\
&+LCM(2,3,9)(1)
\end{align*}$$

The alternating sign depends on the size of the subset of $X$. This is from the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle).